# Can't store user ID in session

Tags: php, html, mysql, session-variables

I'm trying to get the user ID of a logged in user and store it in the session, so that when a user submits something I can add their user ID to the submission to the database. I have a very rough login page, please be kind as I'm very new to it all! I've tried lots of different combinations of things but going by the answers I've seen online, what I currently have should be quite close. If anyone can give me any pointers at all it would be a great help. Thank you!

The login page

```
<?php

session_start();

//Connection and select database go in here

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['Email'];
$mypassword=$_POST['User_Password'];

// To protect MySQL injection 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT User_ID, Email, User_Password FROM $tbl_name WHERE Email='$myusername' and User_Password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row counts table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){

// is_auth to make sure they can view other pages that need credentials.
$_SESSION['is_auth'] = true;
$_SESSION['User_ID'] = $result->User_ID;

// Once the sessions variables have been set, redirect them to the landing page / home page.
header('location: ../View/main.php');
exit;
 }

else {
$error = "Please enter an email and password to login.";
}
header("location:../View/mainUnauthenticated.php");
```

The page that checks if the user is authenticated. I call this at the start of every relevant page

```
<?php

    session_start();
echo $_SESSION['User_ID'];

// Test the session to see if is_auth flag was set (meaning they logged in successfully)

// If test fails, send the user to homepage and prevent rest of page being shown.

if (!isset($_SESSION["is_auth"])) {
header("location: ../View/mainUnauthenticated.php");
exit;
    }
else if (isset($_REQUEST['logout']) && $_REQUEST['logout'] == "true") {
// At any time we can logout by sending a "logout" value which will unset the "is_auth" flag.
// We can also destroy the session if so desired.
unset($_SESSION['is_auth']);
session_destroy();
// After logout, send them back to homepage
header("location: ../View/mainUnauthenticated.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

This is a snippet from one of the pages where I'd like to be able to grab the user ID that I (thought I had!) stored. For now I'm just trying to get it to display in the text field to show it's working.

```
<?php include('../Controller/is_auth.php') 

?>


<p>
<input type="text" name="User_ID" id="User_ID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['User_ID'];?>"/>
</p>
```

Comment: Don't use `mysql` use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead, you are wide open for `mysql injection` too.

Comment: I think I've got it to work now. The problem was the position of my session start, I had put it at the top of my login page but moved it to after the sql query and it's working! Thanks for the help and comments Nytrix and Filip Macek.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recomend you to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) instead of old mysql_query. I is safer to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

To the error: it will be good idea to create some simple "debug" function to see outputs from variables. For example in your login script you use var $result->User_ID. Are you sure that variable exists? Here is my simple debug function you can use:

```
function debug ($var, $name = "Debug") {
    echo "<h2>$name</h2><pre>";
    var_dump($var);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

With this function you can simply check if you get what you are excepting and found a problem. Just call

```
debug($result, "Database output");//or without 2nd parameter
```

PS: create some functions.php that you will be including on every code. When you change some function you don't need to rewrite every file.